# Page Visibility API in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to use Page Visibility API in a Android WebView (v. 54.0.2840.42), but I've got some problems.

For example, a detached WebView always returns `visibilityState = 'visible'`. (It's not make sense! The WebView isn't even attached to window, how could it be visible?!).

And a focused WebView returns `visibilityState = 'visible'` even when screen is locked.

However, in some cases the WebView works. For example when an app is switched for another and it goes to background, a WebView in this app rightly returns `visibilityState = 'hidden'`.

So, can anybody explain something about these wrong behaviors?

Bests,